# Handling clunky join condition (Newbi)

Tags: join, table, sharepoint

(Newbie question I think) [Not a mission critical issue just for my understanding].

I have a situation where I have two SharePoint tables as follows:
Table 1: UserTable:  **user**, **Position**, **Department**, **Work Location**, (user can appear a few times)
Table 2: Application table: **Applications**, **Department**, **Position**, **Location**, (and some other attributes)

Currently we look up the user in table 1, use Position, Department, and Work Location fields to lookup the Application in Table 2. I would like to bridge these two tables so I can query the user and get back all active Applications for them.

I have considered replacing the two tables with 3, with the new table being a join table containing **Department**, **Position**, and **Location**. Assuming this a reasonable approach, it doesn't seem to difficult to do except for one (possibly minor issue). The **Location** field in the two tables are a little different. They share all the same specific locations, but Table 2 has **"All"** as a value and Table 1 does not.

All other issues aside, I am mostly curious what the best practice would be to handle an odd join condition such as this.

Thank you for helping me understand this concept better.